# Subset of GNS Hilbert space generated by von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{M}$ and its commutant $\mathcal{M}^\prime$

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a von Neumann algebra with a faithful normal state $\varphi$. Let $L^2(\mathcal{M}, \varphi)$ be the GNS-Hilbert space associated with $\varphi$ and $\Omega_\mathcal{M}$ the corresponding canonical cyclic vector. We can then view $\mathcal{M}$ as a von Neumann subalgebra of $\mathcal{B}(L^2(\mathcal{M},\varphi))$. Since $\varphi$ is faithful, the vector $\Omega_M$ is both cyclic (i.e. $\mathcal{M}\Omega_\mathcal{M} \subseteq L^2(M,\varphi)$ is dense) and separating (i.e. $x\Omega_\mathcal{M}=0$ implies $x=0$ for every $x \in \mathcal{M}$).This implies that $\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}$ is also cyclic and separating for the commutant $\mathcal{M}^\prime \subseteq \mathcal{B}(L^2 (M,\varphi))$ of $\mathcal{M}$.

I was wondering: for $x \in \mathcal{M}$ consider $x\Omega_{\mathcal{M}} \in L^2 (M,\varphi)$. Is it possible to find $y \in \mathcal{M}^\prime$ such that $x\Omega_\mathcal{M}=y\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}$? Or equivalently, is $\mathcal{M}\Omega_\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{M}^\prime \Omega_\mathcal{M}$?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, I believe this can be solved using standard Tomita-Takesaki theory. In particular, recall that the [Tomita operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomita%E2%80%93Takesaki_theory#Modular_automorphisms_of_a_state) is the unbounded antilinear operator $S_0$ defined as $S_0x\Omega_M=x^*\Omega_M$ for all $x\in M$, where $\Omega_M$ is the cyclic vector on $M$. Note that $S_0^2=I$ and so $S_0=S_0^{-1}$. Furthermore, it is well-known that $S_0$ is a [closable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem_(functional_analysis)#Closed_linear_operators) operator often denoted by $S$.

Now for any $x\in M$, I claim that $S_0xS_0^{-1}=S_0xS_0\in M'$. Let $z,w\in M$, and observe that $$(S_0xS_0)zw\Omega_M=S_0xw^*z^*\Omega=zwx^*\Omega_M$$ similarly, $$z(S_0xS_0)w\Omega_M=zS_0xw^*\Omega_M=zwx^*\Omega_M$$ and so we can conclude that $S_0xS_0\in M'$. So given an $x\in M$, you can conjugate it with the Tomita operator to get a $y=S_0xS_0\in M'$ or vice versa.

I'm fairly new to Tomita-Takasaki theory and von Neumann algebras in general, so I apologized in advance if I've made any egregious errors.

**Edit:** As noted in the comments I am unable to show that the operator $S_0xS_0$ is actually bounded. In the case that $M$ is semi-finite and $\varphi$ is a tracial state it follows that $S$ is actually a unitary and so clearly $SxS$ is bounded but is this true only when $\varphi$ is tracial?

Comment: Dear Condo, thanks for your answer! If $\varphi$ is tracial your approach will work, but I think the problem is that, in general, $S_0 x S_0$ will not be bounded and hence not an element in $M^\prime$...

Comment: Can we not show it's bounded? Since $\Omega_M$ is cyclic, we consider $x\in M$ and the values $\|S_0xS_0m\Omega_M\|$ for all $m\in M$, but $\|S_0xS_0m\Omega_M\|=\|mx^*\Omega\|$ is bounded for all $m\in M$, no?

Comment: The operator $S_0 x S_0$ (or rather $SxS$) has to be bounded in the sense that $\sup_{m \in \mathcal{M}} \Vert S_0 x S_0 m\Omega_{\mathcal{M}} \Vert / \Vert  m \Omega_{\mathcal{M}} \Vert < \infty$, otherwise $S_0 x S_0 \notin \mathcal{B}(L^2(\mathcal{M},\varphi))$. I don't see why this should hold in general.

Comment: Suppose $\sup_{m\in M}\|SxSm\Omega_M\|/\|m\Omega_M\|$ is unbounded, then by my first comment there is an $m\in M$ such that $\|mx^*\Omega_M\|$ is unbounded, but $mx^*\in M\subset B(L^2(M,\varphi)$ for all $m$ since $M$ is closed under $*$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: No, it might for instance be possible that there exists a sequence $(m_i)_{i \in  \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{M}$ for which $\Vert m_i x^\ast \Omega_{M} \Vert$ grows to infinity and for which $\Vert m_i \Omega_{M} \Vert \leq 1$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$. Then the supremum is infinite and $SxS$ is unbounded.

Comment: @worldreporter14 ah thank you, your discussion has been very helpful. I was not fully appreciating the fact that $\lim_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\|m_i\Omega_M\|$ can be $0$ while $\lim_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\|m_i^*\Omega_M\|$ can be $\infty$, which is why $S_0$ is unbounded in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, so I'm not sure if an answer is still needed at this point, but no, $\mathcal{M}\Omega_{\mathcal{M}} = \mathcal{M}'\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}$ need not happen. As already discussed in @Condo's answer and the discussion in the comments, for the case where $\varphi$ is tracial this necessarily holds. When $\varphi$ is not tracial, $S_0xS_0$ where $S_0$ is the possibly unbounded involution might not be bounded for all $x \in \mathcal{M}$, so @Condo's answer would not apply. If one thinks more about this, all such operators being bounded is actually required for $\mathcal{M}\Omega_{\mathcal{M}} = \mathcal{M}'\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}$. Indeed, for any $T \in \mathcal{M}'$, we observe that $T(x\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}) = x(T\Omega_{\mathcal{M}})$ for any $x \in \mathcal{M}$, so if $y\Omega_{\mathcal{M}} = T\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}$, then $T(x\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}) = xy\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}$ and $T = S_0y^*S_0$. Hence, if we were to have $\mathcal{M}\Omega_{\mathcal{M}} = \mathcal{M}'\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}$, we must have $S_0xS_0$ is bounded for all $x \in \mathcal{M}$.

With this in mind, it's not hard to construct a counterexample. For example, one may choose $\mathcal{M} = \mathbb{B}(l^2)$ and $\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{e}\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\langle e_n, xe_n\rangle$. Let $x \in \mathcal{M}$ be the adjoint of the unilateral shift, $p_n$ be the rank-one projection onto $\textrm{span}\{e_n\}$. Then for $n > 1$, $||S_0xS_0p_n\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}||^2 = ||p_nx^*\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}||^2 = \varphi(xp_nx^*) = \varphi(p_{n - 1}) = \frac{1}{(n - 1)!e}$ and $||p_n\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}||^2 = \varphi(p_n) = \frac{1}{n!e}$, so $\frac{||S_0xS_0p_n\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}||}{||p_n\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}||} = \sqrt{n} \rightarrow \infty$, so $S_0xS_0$ is not bounded. (In particular, this means that $x^*\Omega_{\mathcal{M}} \notin \mathcal{M}'\Omega_{\mathcal{M}}$.)